# Firebase dynamic link is not resolving in Xamarin Forms iOS

Tags: firebase, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, nuget-package, firebase-dynamic-links

I am using Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.DynamicLinks 2.3.1.1 for dynamic links, Earlier it was working fine but recently it is not working. While trying to extract the short link, long link getting null. Is anyone knows why it is not working?

I have updated to the latest version (4.0.1) and its working fine. It not working any of the previous version of NuGet packages.

Comment: facing the same problem... I Have not been able to test with 4.0.1 due to linking Native linking error. Did you face native linking errors when upgrading?  I am also running Birdie.FirebasePushNotification nuget

Comment: My production app also suddenly stopped working.

Comment: @GisonGeorge did you figure out the solution?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question.  The Dynamic links are not working either on Firebase's end who choose to discontinue their old library or due to the newest IOS update 13.3. I say this because my app that is in production had its links working fine then they suddenly stopped working.

My current solution was to update Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.DynamicLinks to (4.0.1) and I was able to once again process the long url with its parameters.

A few things to note if you have other libraries such as Firestore, Analytics, Notifications etc.
You might run into linker failed exceptions. They occur because

```
Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.DynamicLinks (3.0.2.1) and prior depended on
Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Core (>= 5.1.3) and the working
Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.DynamicLinks (4.0.1.1) references 
Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Core (>= 6.1.0.1) Somehow they reference methods that are no longer available.
```

The linking failed is fixed by checking each of your nuGets and manually installing their respective nuGets that reference ...iOS.Core (>= 6.1.0.1) : For example:
if you use Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Storage (2.0.0) manually install

```
Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Storage (3.4.0.1) because 
Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Storage (2.0.0) references
Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Storage (>= 3.0.2) which in turn references:
Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Core (>= 5.1.3) and it will cause native linking failed
```

And lastly, in my case Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.DynamicLinks (4.0.1.1) will make your method for generating ShortLinks, stop working too:

```
In Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.DynamicLinks (3.0.2.1) you would build your 
DynamicLinkComponents with:
var shareLink = DynamicLinkComponents.FromLink(linkParameters, 
"YOUR_DOMAIN.page.link");

Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.DynamicLinks (4.0.1.1) recomends you use 
DynamicLinkComponents.Create(YOURlinkParameters, "YOUR_DOMAIN.page.link");
but it would return a null DynamicLinkComponents so i fixed by doing:
var shareLink = new DynamicLinkComponents();
shareLink.Link = YOURlinkParameters;
shareLink.Domain = "https://YOUR_DOMAIN.page.link";
```

I spent a week trying to troubleshoot this error and really hope others are able to see this and save you valuable time.

Comment: Is there any documentation for firebase not supporting older versions?

Comment: I lean more towards the IOS update being the cause of the problem. Since IOS has it's own Universal Link Handler any changes they make will affect it. Also because my production Android app works no problem and they use the same Nuget

Answer (score 0):

A work around to get Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.DynamicLinks 3.0.2.1 working (should work on 2.3.1.1 as well) is to have the IOS device open the link in the browser which will then redirect them back to the app.

The flow is Dynamic link > App [short link] > Browser > App with [long link].

Dynamic links are formatted "domain.page.link/ShortSequence" and long links parameters have "domain.page.link/?". You can look for the '?' to decide weather to process url or to redirect user as follows:

```
public override bool ContinueUserActivity(UIApplication application, 
NSUserActivity userActivity, UIApplicationRestorationHandler completionHandler)
{
 if (userActivity.ActivityType == NSUserActivityType.BrowsingWeb)
   {
    var sharedLink = userActivity.WebPageUrl;
    if (!sharedLink.ToString().Contains("domain.page.link/?")){
       await Launcher.OpenAsync(new Uri(sharedLink.ToString()));
       return;
    }
    var handled = DynamicLinks.SharedInstance.FromUniversalLinkUrl(sharedLink);
    //Process your DynamicLink parameters
}
return true;
}
```